# Run MySQL query on remote machine through ssh in command line

Tags: mysql, ssh, remote-access

I am trying to run MySQL query on remote machine with this command:

```
ssh user@192.168.2.26 "mysql -uroot -proot -e \"use test";""
```

I am not able to use that database.

Please suggest a working command.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql -h host -u root -proot -e "show databases;";
```

Comment: For Scripting I'd look into using ~/my.cnf or MYSQL_PWD Variable >> see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227648/mysqldump-via-crontab-pass-password-hashed-password-file-so-i-can-use-via-c/227664#227664

Comment: I think the last semicolon is not necessary

Comment: To me the right answer is the one from  @King-Wzrd. This one lack the part of ssh command and doesn't give indication about quotes which are the real problem to solve the question

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
ssh root@host "mysql database -e 'query to run on table_name; more queries to run;'"
```

Same can be done with `user@host` if that user has permission to execute SQL queries let alone launch mysql in general. Using `-e` is the same as `--execute`, which will run whatever you put within the trailing quotes (single or double) and quit. The standard output format would be the same as you would see using `--batch`.

Comment: Good description why problem happens and quotes required https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212298/18674

Answer (score 6):

MySql seems to have a special command line syntax which includes the database.

mysql -u user -p -e 'SQL Query' database

This documentation is rather old but I got it to work

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-sql-query-directly-on-the-command-line/

Final working command with ssh:

ssh user@host "mysql -u user -e 'show tables;' databasename"

Comment: Thanks!  The higher responses weren't working for me but yours did.  Personally I prefer to use " -D databasename " before the " -e query " simply because it's more explicit - but both worked for me like a charm.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

This ended up working for me in a bash script:

```
query='USE [database]; SELECT ...'   
mysql='mysql -u [username] -p[password] -e '"'""$query""'"
ssh [username]@[server] -t "$mysql"
```

If you want to make it more safe then add a prompt for the password instead of storing it somewhere potentially unsafe.

Comment: Hi @OZZIE the output is having special character like + and - 
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
how to get ride of this in query

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me after a few tests (basically same answer as @King-Wzrd):

```
ssh -t kom "mysql -uroot -p -e 'show databases;'"
ssh -t kom "mysql -uroot -p < /home/ling/websites/jin_test/.deploy/tmp.sql"
```

The "trick" was the quotes around the command.

The **-t** option allows for prompting password interactively via the remote shell.

The **kom** here is just a ssh config identifier defined in my **~/.ssh/config** file (see more here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/).

Answer (score 1):

Running this from my Host environment against MySQL within my Homestead VM produced a nice result... although I did have to set the root password from within the VM first in order for it to work.

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.10.10 mysql -h localhost -u root -p -e "'SELECT * FROM user;' mysql";
```